# Chaining Task.Factory.FromAsync and ContinueWith vs. await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, task-parallel-library, async-await

Consider an MVC4 / NET 4.5 asynchronous action method that has two IO-bound, in-order operations to do, both of which follow the IAsyncResult pattern.  Below I've created a simple example using the System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace.  Although I've long been a fan of the TPL and other async models in .NET (as well as callback-heavy models like node.js), I'm finally getting around to async/await.

As shown with 'await', it returns the proper result, but I've been confounded on a way to get the same result with .ContinueWith and Task.Factory.FromAsync, the latter which usefully relieves the code of the mess of dealing with IAsyncResult or the syntactical mess of callbacks.

Maybe my sample code is already doing things in the most optimal way? .ContinueWith seems like the more idiomatic approach (or is it?) but I could not find any way to chain a new Task as a continuation; a Func continuation isn't going to cut it here without devolving.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AjaxStuff()
    {
        var c = new LdapConnection(string.Empty);

        var t1 = Task.Factory.FromAsync<string>(
            c.BeginSendRequest(new SearchRequest(string.Empty, "(&(objectClass=*))", SearchScope.Base, "defaultNamingContext"), PartialResultProcessing.NoPartialResultSupport, null, null),
            iar =>
            {
                return ((SearchResponse)c.EndSendRequest(iar)).Entries[0].Attributes["defaultNamingContext"][0].ToString();
            });

        var nc = await t1;

        var t2 = Task.Factory.FromAsync<string>(
            c.BeginSendRequest(new SearchRequest(nc, "(&(givenName=steve))", SearchScope.Subtree), PartialResultProcessing.NoPartialResultSupport, null, null),
            iar =>
            {
                var result = (SearchResponse)c.EndSendRequest(iar);
                return result.Entries.Count > 0 ? result.Entries[0].DistinguishedName : "no such thing";
            });

        return this.PartialView("AjaxStuff", await t2);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use await? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: You should be able to add a continuation to `t1` without problems. You probably need to call Unwrap on the resulting task.

Comment: I'm not at all opposed to using await if it's the more idiomatic way.  Re. adding a continuation, that works perfectly, but the ContinueWith style continuation doesn't seem compatible with a second FromAsync task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`await` certainly results in cleaner code than `ContinueWith`.

That said, it's easier to use `FromAsync` without a specified callback. I also prefer to wrap `FromAsync` in a simple extension method:

```
public static Task<DirectoryResponse> SendRequestAsync(this LdapConnection c, DirectoryRequest request, PrtialResultProcessing partialMode)
{
    return Task.Factory<DirectoryResponse>.FromAsync(c.BeginSendRequest, c.EndSendRequest, request, partialMode, null);
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AjaxStuff()
{
    var c = new LdapConnection(string.Empty);

    var result1 = await c.SendRequestAsync(new SearchRequest(string.Empty, "(&(objectClass=*))", SearchScope.Base, "defaultNamingContext"), PartialResultProcessing.NoPartialResultSupport);
    var nc = ((SearchResponse)result1).Entries[0].Attributes["defaultNamingContext"][0].ToString();

    var result2 = (SearchResponse)(await c.SendRequestAsync(new SearchRequest(nc, "(&(givenName=steve))", SearchScope.Subtree), PartialResultProcessing.NoPartialResultSupport)));
    var dn = result2.Entries.Count > 0 ? result2.Entries[0].DistinguishedName : "no such thing";

    return this.PartialView("AjaxStuff", dn);
}
```

By keeping your `FromAsync` code simple, you're moving all the logic into a single method, and `await` makes it much more readable.

Comment: Works for me and I like the extension method idea -- only adjustment is that the method no longer returns Task<ActionResult>,  just a plain ActionResult with a string model.  Is there any downside at all to this w.r.t. MVC?

Comment: @SKradel: I'm not sure what you mean. Since `AjaxStuff` uses `await`, it must be `async` and would have to return `Task<ActionResult>` instead of `ActionResult`.

Comment: Ah, of course you are right.  I'll (totally ineffectually) blame my confusion on it being a warm Friday afternoon.